# Linq To SQL - How to disable loading of associations?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, associations

I have an entity which is has one-to-many association (it has a reference to a collection of other associated items).

Sometimes I need to load a set of these entities from a database and place them in a list which can hold them in memory for some time. As the result I get a list of entities with all associations. But the problem is that I need these entities without associations.

Can I somehow manually disable of loading associations in some situations?

Comment: Reading up on "disconnected [or detached] entities" (e.g. http://linq2sqleb.codeplex.com/) is a good place to start. [Un]fortunately the DLO can only be specified *per context*.

Comment: http://complexitykills.blogspot.com/2008/03/disconnected-linq-to-sql-tips-part-1.html <-- that's what I was looking for (linked from previous link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a switch or parameter to disable it, but you constrain the result data by defining it manually. 
So if you have a table person which has a foreign key FamilyId which points to the family(with an ID, Name, Comment column) table, because family can have one or more persons, but a person can only be in one family.
If you want to have all families, but not the assigned persons, you can call:

```
var result = datacontext.Families.Select( s => new { ID = s.ID, Name = s.Name, Comment = s.Comment});
```

The result is a list of objects which have only the properties from the select expression.